# Two threads writing to the same file

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have multiple threads (let's say two, for now), each of which retrieves an HTML page and writes its content to a file.  The caveat is that each thread wants to write to the same output file. The class with the run() method is a static inner class.  The approach I would like to take is to have each thread put the content it wants to write into a queue. THEN, after the thread is finished (or all the threads have finished), to iterate over the queues and print the contents to the file.  I'm not sure how to implement this.  Again, the class that implements the runnable interface is static.  I'm not well-versed in concurrency and not necessarily looking to do anything fancy. Any suggestions for a simple implementation?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [`BlockingQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) from the `java.util.concurrent` package. Each of your threads would put its output into the queue, and a third thread would get the elements out of the queue and write them to the file. On the API page for Blocking Queue is an example that you should be able to use for your implementation. You only need to provide the implementation for `produce` and `consume` and you are done.

Comment: The example shows both the consumer and producer classes being non-static. Would it work if both classes are static?

Comment: Well, as the consumer and producer are threads they cannot be static. Threads in Java implement the Runnable interface, and must be instantiated to be executed. But of course you could refactor the methods to insert your elements into the queue and get them out into static methods, depending on the program design you have.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a single threaded ExecutorService.  This can be used to write the data as it is produced (rather than having to wait.

```
static final ExecutorService logger = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

static void writeToFile(final FileOutputStream fos, final String text) {
    logger.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                fos.write(text.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `synchronized` blocks aswell.

Comment: Do the synchronized blocks go in the run() method of the class that implements Runnable?  Could you please post or point me in the direction of an example?

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on your description, this is how I think your producers should look:

```
private static final int CAPACITY = 10; // whatever you like here.
private static Object locker = new Object();
private static Queue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(CAPACITY);

private static class ThreadTask implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // retrieve page            
        // add result to queue
    }       
}
```

Of course, you can execute these ThreadTasks in an Executor, in order to better use the system resources and also your consumer thread can run simultaneously with the producers if you implement a producer-consumer queue system.

Comment: Not quite sure you realize that this is already half of the producer-consumer queue system, you have the producer, you have the queue, you now only need a consumer thread. Additionally, you should drop the synchronized, as ArrayBlockingQueue (an implementation of BlockingQueue) is made for concurrent access. Also, as long as there is no consumer running concurrently you might want to drop the capacity, else your program is going to block.

Comment: I've considered the capacity to be the total number of pages you want to write. The queue size will equal the capacity when the computation finishes. For the thread safety, you are right, I edited.

Comment: Ah, alright. If the program will always fetch the same number of pages that makes sense.